# Split data in Amazon Athena / Presto by varchar column

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I want to split data in Amazon Athena database by `varchar` column on similar parts. If I could convert `varchar` to `integer` I would use just
`some_hash_function(data) mod n`. But Athena's hash functions return `varbinary` and it can't be cast to `integer`.

So, is it possible to solve this problem in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert an 8 byte `varbinary` into a `bigint` using the  [`from_big_endian_64`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html#from_big_endian_64) function.  Here is a full example:

`select from_big_endian_64(substr(sha256(to_utf8('test')), 1, 8));`

Comment: substr will not work in Athena directly on the binary datatype, so you will also need to convert to string and then back again (to_hex, from_hex)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Dain answer is correct, but there is a slight remark: since `substr` takes `varchar` as a first argument, but `sha256` returns `varbinary` that code will fail.

Here is a working alternative:

`from_big_endian_64(xxhash64(to_utf8(user_id)))`

Comment: substr will not work in Athena directly on the binary datatype, so you will also need to convert to string and then back again (to_hex, from_hex) 
e.g. 

`from_big_endian_64(from_hex(substr(to_hex(md5(to_utf8(user_id || 'experiment_name'))),1,16)))`